# Error with Kivy Login screen and popup

Tags: python, kivy

I want to make a login page which accepts username and password. Upon validation of both a popup message should be displayed showing the message: "Login successful " or else show the popup message "Login failed".
I tried doing it but I don't know where I went wrong. Any help would be much appreciated. My code is as follows(saved as Login.py):

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup

Builder.load_string("""

<LoginScreen@Login>:
canvas:

    Rectangle:
        source: 'b.png'
        pos: self.pos
        size: self.size
Label:
    text: "PLEASE LOGIN OR SIGN UP"
    center_x: (root.width/2) 
    top: (root.top/2)+ 200
    font_size: 25

TextInput:
    id: txtuname
    center_x: (root.width/2) 
    top: (root.top/2)+ 100
    size_hint: None,None
    multiline: False
    hint_text: "username"
    size: 250, 40
    max_lines: 1
    valign: 'middle'
    halign: 'center'
    on_text_validate: root.validate();

TextInput:
    id: txtpswd
    multiline: False
    center_x: (root.width/2) 
    top: (root.top/2)+ 50
    size_hint: None,None
    hint_text: "password"
    size: 250, 40
    max_lines: 1
    valign: 'middle'
    halign: 'center'
    on_text_validate: root.validate();
    password: True

Button:
    id: btnlogin
    size: 90,35
    pos: 300, 250
    font_size: 18
    background_color: (1,1,1,0.1)
    text: "Login"
    on_press: root.validate(txtuname.text,txtpswd.text)

Button:
    text: "Sign Up"
    size: 90,35
    pos: 400, 250
    font_size: 18
    background_color: (1,1,1,0.1)

<CustomPopup>:
Button:
    id: btnpopup
    text: "Login successfull"
    size_hint: .5, .5
    on_press: root.dismiss()
""")

class LoginScreen(Widget):
    def validate(self,txtuname,txtpswd): 
        if txtuname == "username" and txtpswd == "password": 
            print(txtuname,txtpswd)
            b = Button(on_press=self.show_popup)
            return b
        else: 
            print("Login failed")

class CustomPopup(Popup):
    def show_popup(self, b):
        p = CustomPopup()
        p.open()

class LoginApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return LoginScreen()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    LoginApp().run()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all remove `on_text_validate: root.validate();` of both `TextInput`s because you do the validation on sign_in button press. You could create a class like this as a popup:

```
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup    
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.core.window import Window


class Alert(Popup):

    def __init__(self, title, text):
        super(Alert, self).__init__()
        content = AnchorLayout(anchor_x='center', anchor_y='bottom')
        content.add_widget(
            Label(text=text, halign='left', valign='top')
        )
        ok_button = Button(text='Ok', size_hint=(None, None), size=(Window.width / 5, Window.height / 5))
        content.add_widget(ok_button)

        popup = Popup(
            title=title,
            content=content,
            size_hint=(None, None),
            size=(Window.width / 3, Window.height / 3),
            auto_dismiss=True,
        )
        ok_button.bind(on_press=popup.dismiss)
        popup.open()
```

Then in your `validate()` method

```
def validate(self,txtuname,txtpswd): 
    # if inputs are valid:
        Alert(title='yeah!', text='inputs are valid')
    # else:
        Alert(title='oops!', text='invalid inputs')
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to kivy. I think my coding will help you..

```
def check_user(self):
    obj=CustomPopup()
    if self.ids.unam.text=='' or self.ids.pas.text=='':
        obj.call_pops('Fill up please!','Some fields are empty!')
    else:
        if self.ids.unam.text=='sri' and self.ids.pas.text=='sri':
            self.manager.current='Feed'
            t="Success"
            c="Logged in successfully!"
            obj.call_pops(t,c)
            self.ids.unam.text=''
            self.ids.pas.text=''
        else:
            print "Warning"
            t="Warning"
            c="Wrong User or Password!"
            obj.call_pops(t,c)


class CustomPopup(Popup):
    def call_pops(self,tit,conten):
        cont=Button(text=conten)
        pop=Popup(title=tit,content=cont,size_hint=(None, None), size=(250, 150),auto_dismiss=True)
        pop.open()
        cont.bind(on_press=pop.dismiss)
```